# Accessing variable from enclosing scope at runtime

Tags: scala

I am working to implement a DSL that will - among other things - allow me to wrap a block of code in a *context*. For simplicity, the context in this example is just a string.

The code block wrapped by that *context* could contain anything, but will also contain calls to *func1*. Now, within func1 I would like to have access to the ID of the enclosing context.

```
def func1() = {
    // Would like to access the context ID here
    // i.e. "MY_CONTEXT"
}

def func2()(implicit x: String) = {
    // Can access x here, but that would be "OTHER".
}


def context(id: String)(body: => Unit) = {
   // How can body make use of id ?
   body
}

implicit val c = "OTHER"
context("MY_CONTEXT") {
  func1()
  func2()
}
```

I have looked into using an implicit parameter. This can be seen with func2. However, it seems that this would need to be declared just above the call to context. This defeats the purpose, as I only want to specify it with the context call.

I hope the example code is enough to illustrate the problem. Any suggestion on how to keep the context(id)(body) construct as shown and be able to access the context ID within func1? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a state monad to me. Only it's not as simple as you want.

Comment: @VictorMoroz, thank you for the hint. Am looking into this.